# SqlDataAdapter, SqlCommand dropping the leading numbers from string

Tags: c#, sqlclient

I am trying to execute a SQL statement with a where clause which looks like

```
 string s2 = "Select * from idtyfile where oysterid=" + id ;
 SqlCommand da2 = new SqlCommand(s2, con); or 
 SqlAdapter da2 = new SqlAdapter(s2, con);
```

Both of these are failing when I am trying to execute them

```
da2.ExecuteReader();
```

the data in ID looks like

```
ID
43PCOU5T
ZP6RAEJ0
```

For some reason both of these queries are failing on these kind of data.

Comment: why not format the query string and pass id as a parameter..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the single quotes in your select command which is what is making your original `SELECT` fail.  However I would like to note that you should always parameterize and encapsulate your `SqlCommand` / `SqlConnection` in a `using` statement.  The following would be a cleaner more secure way to solve your problem.

```
        string s2 = "Select * from idtyfile where oysterid=@id";
        DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s2, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            conn.Open();
            myDataTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }
```

For some educational resources, you should look at the following links.

[MSDN Reference for the `using` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

[MSDN Reference for `SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)  -- Look at the `Parameters` property.

Comment: The dataReader is also a disposable object and should be wrapped with a using statement.

Comment: I didn't instantiate a reader object.  Just called the `ExecuteReader` extension method on the `SqlCommand` it will be disposed of with the `SqlCommand`.  Hopefully the OP knows what to do with the data coming from the `cmd.ExecuteReader()`.

Comment: Actually I want to store the values I get from Select statement to DataTable. Can I use SQL Adapter instead of SQL Command?

Comment: @John answer is updated to demonstrate loading a `DataTable` from the `ExecuteReader` method.